# How to create a drop down in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple drop down in react and I am facing two issues. The code that I have is:

```
import React from "react";

class EditEmployee extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            salary:''
        }
     }

    validateSalary=(e)=>{
       // e.persist();
        var val=e.target.value;
        this.setState((prevState)=>{prevState.salary=val})
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Salary:</label>
                    <select onChange={this.validateSalary} className="form-control" value={this.state.salary}>
                        <option value="20000">20000</option>
                        <option value="30000">30000</option>
                        <option value="40000">40000</option>
                        <option value="50000">50000</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default EditEmployee
```

Issue 1 - When I select an option, I am able to get the value in the console, but the drop down is not showing the selected value. I am setting the state properly and I am not sure why is it not updating the view.

Issue 2 - If I directly access the event inside setState I get an warning about synthetic event and the code does not work. Why do I need e.persist() to avoid it?

Comment: "I am setting the state properly" - no, you're not :)

Comment: @jnylen, just realized that :) Should have been this.setState(prev=>{salary:val})

Comment: previous state is required when you want to push elements to an array or in certain cases when you really need previous state value. But here just normal state works for you as others mentioned

Comment: @Think-Twice, also why do I need e.persist()?

Comment: By the time your `setState` callback runs, the event has already expired.

Comment: @codingsplash If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validateSalary(e){
       // e.persist();
        var val=e.target.value;
        this.setState({
           salary = val
        });
    }


<select onChange={e => this.validateSalary(e)} className="form-control" value={this.state.salary}>
                        <option value="20000">20000</option>
                        <option value="30000">30000</option>
                        <option value="40000">40000</option>
                        <option value="50000">50000</option>
                    </select>
```

**OR**
you need to change your function

```
validateSalary=(e)=> {
   var val = e.target.value;
   this.setState({
       salary = val
    });
}
```

Can you try this code. I think it is problem in some callback

Comment: You no need to pass event from here onChange={e => this.validateSalary(e)}. This onChange={this.validateSalary} sends event by default. Isn't it?

Comment: @Think-Twice yes, but if you use `this.validateSalary` only then you need to bind that method or you need to write callback for this

Comment: He is already using arrow function and no need to bind a function again

Comment: @Think-Twice, yes correct, we can write both the way but he need to change into `var val=e.target.value;
        this.setState({
           salary = val
        });`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this change

```
validateSalary=(e)=> {
   let val = e.target.value;
   this.setState({salary:val})
}
```

Comment: Using var has to be avoided. Since OP is already using arrow function so would recommend using let or const instead of var. ES6 suggests avoid using var

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your both the issues.

```
import React from "react";
class EditEmployee extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    salary: ""
  };
}

validateSalary = e => {
  // e.persist();
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value }, function() {
    console.log(this.state);
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Salary:</label>
        <select
          name="salary"
          onChange={this.validateSalary}
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.salary}
        >
          <option value="">Please select salary</option>
          <option value="20000">20000</option>
          <option value="30000">30000</option>
          <option value="40000">40000</option>
          <option value="50000">50000</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
}
export default EditEmployee;
```

i'm consoling the state after state is updated, because if you console the state outside you will get previous state value.